# Converting a date in string format(17-MAR-15 09.11.39.395000 AM) to datetime format?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to convert this "17-MAR-15 09.11.39.395000 AM" to datetime format.

I have tried below things but it is not working

`df = df.withColumn("created_date", F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp("created_date", 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a'), 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'))`
`df = df.withColumn("created_date", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("created_date"), 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a').cast("timestamp"))`

Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html) with the date_format as - `dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a`

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
CREATED_DATE
17-MAR-15 09.11.39.395000 AM
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+----------------------------+
|CREATED_DATE                |
+----------------------------+
|17-MAR-15 09.11.39.395000 AM|
+----------------------------+
```

#### To Timestamp

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('CREATED_DATE_TIME',F.to_timestamp(F.col('CREATED_DATE'),'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a'))

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+----------------------------+-----------------------+
|CREATED_DATE                |CREATED_DATE_TIME      |
+----------------------------+-----------------------+
|17-MAR-15 09.11.39.395000 AM|2015-03-17 09:11:39.395|
+----------------------------+-----------------------+

sparkDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- CREATED_DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATED_DATE_TIME: timestamp (nullable = true)
```